# JavaScript Timer Based Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to make a simple timer based popup. 
once the timer reach 10 second popup will be visible.
timer should pause or stop, after clicking on 'ok' button of popup, timer should restart from 0. please help

https://jsfiddle.net/ckf0g9qj/5/

```js
var span = document.querySelector("#time");
countDown(0);

function countDown(counter) {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var minutes = ((counter / 60) | 0) + "";
    var seconds = (counter % 60) + "";
    var format = "" +
      new Array(3 - minutes.length).join("0") + minutes + ':' + new Array(3 - seconds.length).join("0") + seconds;
    span.innerHTML = format;
    counter++;

    if (seconds == 10) {
      // $("#timeModal").modal(); BS model box open
      // countDown(0);
      document.getElementById("popup").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
  }, 1e3)
}

function timerReset() {
  countDown(0);
  alert("ok");
  document.getElementById("popup").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: what's you problem actually? you fiddle works the way you seem to ask for.. apart from the fact that the interval is never cleared and you may have several ones running at the same time, it works. (you should clear the interval on `timerReset`, but the function must be able to access the `interval` var to do it)

Answer (score 0):

use `clearInterval` when you reach `seconds == 10` condition

I think this is what you are looking for:

```css
#popup {
  width:200px; 
height:200px;
border:solid 1px red; 
visibility:hidden;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
<div id="popup">
  <button id="ok" onclick="timerReset()">
Ok
</button>
</div>

<script>
  var span = document.querySelector("#time");
  countDown(0);

  function countDown(counter) {

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var minutes = ((counter / 60) | 0) + "";
      var seconds = (counter % 60) + "";
      var format = "" +
        new Array(3 - minutes.length).join("0") + minutes +
        ':' +
        new Array(3 - seconds.length).join("0") + seconds;

      span.innerHTML = format;
      counter++;
      if (seconds == 10) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        // $("#timeModal").modal(); BS model box open
        // countDown(0);
        document.getElementById("popup").style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    }, 1e3)
  }

  function timerReset() {
    countDown(0);
    alert("ok");
    document.getElementById("popup").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
</script>
```